# PHP Array to interger conversion

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array generated by an object. I want to be able to use each value as an integer, but I'm getting `can not convert to integer` error.

It has something to do with these double quotes I can't get rid of. I've tried several things like the `intval` function, but nothing seems to be working.

```
<?php
$keys = $dataProvider->keys;
print_r($keys);
?>
```

This is what it looks like in source

```
"    

  Array
  (
    [0] = 269
    [1] = 270

  )


"
```

Comment: where is your code actually throwing the error? I can see how the array might be created, but not where it's being used

Comment: use var_dump instead of print_r

Comment: I suspect something is off with your $keys array (var_dump would help identify this).  PHP Fiddle [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vcpy-7dwu)

Comment: So, keys is a string? or an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can type [cast that array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in integer like this:

```
$intArray = [];
foreach($dataProvider->keys as $val) {
   $intArray[] = (int) $val;
}

// ToDo with $intArray
```